# Is there a way to access the Components contained by a PanedWindow in python tkinter?

Tags: python, swing, tkinter, parent-child, ttkbootstrap

I have to access the components contained by a tkinter.PanedWindow so I can modify the value of the amountused of the ttkbootsatrap.Meter with the method update().

Is there a funcition similar to the Java Swing `JPanel.getComponents()` in tkinter or ttkbootstrap?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    def buildChart(self):

        chartPanel = tk.PanedWindow(self.parent_window, orient=tk.VERTICAL, borderwidth=0)

        meter = ttk.Meter(
            metersize = self.meter_radius,
            padding = self.padding,
            amountused = 25,
            metertype = self.meter_type,
            subtext = self.subtext,
            interactive = self.isInteractive,
        )
        meter.pack(expand=True)
        chartPanel.add(meter)

        return chartPanel 

    def updateValue(panel, value):
        for c in panel.getComponents(): # <- This is where i would implement the function instead of "panel.getComponents()" (which, ofcourse, does not work)
            if isinstance(c, ttk.Meter):
                meter.configure(amountused = value)
```

I come from a java background, hope this is not a dumb question.
Thank you in  advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `panes` method returns an ordered list of the widgets managed by the paned window. Unfortunately it returns a low level Tcl object rather than python objects.

Fortunately, there's a fairly easy way to translate the low level object to the python object. The lower level object has a `string` attribute that contains the internal name of the widget, or you can use the `str` method on it. Python widgets have a method named `nametowidget` which can take the internal name and convert it to the python object.

So, using that information you can loop over the widgets like this (assuming `panel` represents the PanedWindow widget):

```
def updateValue(panel, value):
    for obj in panel.panes():
        c = panel.nametowidget(str(obj))
        if isinstance(c, ttk.Meter):
            ...
```